# Crashlytics logs missed just before the Intentional crash

Tags: android, crashlytics

In one of the Android  application when i used Crashlytics i noticed i am missing few of the logs  that are just before the  intentional crash from code blocks like

```
String obj=null;
obj.toString();
```

actually on the flow of the program i have lot of crashlytics operations after starting crashlytics  as

```
Crashlytics.start(context);
```

on doing several operations as

```
Crashlytics.log(message);
Crashlytics.log(priority, tag, msg) 
Crashlytics.logException(throwable);
```

and than on doing

```
String obj=null;
obj.toString();
```

i am missing few of the Crashlytics logs which are just before the crash.

I want to ask that if there is any mechanism to get all the custom Crashlytics logs reported to see them on Dashboard!!

Comment: Did you ever get around this problem? I have the same problem with non-exception, and the non-fatal exceptions are reported separately, but without any logs.